# How to add a file to download into Jenkins/Hudson plugin

Tags: jenkins, hudson

I need to add a file for downloading to a plugin, which provides a build step. I want to put link to it into a HTML help file for a build step field, and also be able to paste the link to e-mails etc.

Let's assume this is just a simple, plain plugin project, with `pom.xml` having this:

```
<groupId>my.jenkins.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>my-special-plugin</artifactId>
<name>My Special Plugin</name>
```

Name of the downloadable is `myspecialtool.exe`

### Question:

1. Where to put the file under the plugin project source
2. What is the download URL, assuming Jenkins is at `http://ciserver:8080`
3. What to write to a help HTML file to link to it "properly" (if different from above)

Hoping to get a good reference answer: clear, short and to-the-point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store data that you want to be able to address as 'web data' in [`src/main/webapp`](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial#Plugintutorial-src/main/webapp) in your plugin project.

That directory should be addressable as `/plugin/<name of your plugin>` (from '[Jenkins Continuous Integration Cookbook](http://books.google.com/books?id=zBUCFWlMkrwC&lpg=PA276&ots=AMjjguipoV&dq=jenkins%20plugin%20src/main/webapp&pg=PA276#v=onepage&q=jenkins%20plugin%20src/main/webapp&f=false)')

---

Answers to the enumerated questions:

1. Put file under `src/main/webapp`, perhaps in a sub-folder, so:
   `src/main/webapp/download/myspecialtool.exe`
2. URL to that is is then:
   `http://ciserver:8080/plugin/my-special-plugin/download/myspecialtool.exe`
3. Link to put to help HTML files:
   `/plugin/my-special-plugin/download/myspecialtool.exe`